# Making master pdf editor default for .pdf files

Tags: 14.04, master-pdf-editor

I have followed the answer posted by Moderator Mitch user 59676 and created mpe.desktop file, right clicked on the file and 'open with other application' - 'show other applications' did not list master PDF editor so unable to make as default.

Answer (score 0):

Add `%f` at last  in `Exec` of Desktop file (and put it in `/usr/share/applications`). So-that it is available as open-with-other-applications.

---

If `MasterPdfEditor.desktop` is placed in `/usr/share/applications`, then

Open `sudo gedit /etc/gnome/defaults.list`

And Replace:-

`application/pdf=evince.desktop` with `application/pdf=MasterPdfEditor.desktop`

This will set Master Pdf Editor as default for pdf files.

For instance, You can replace all `evince.desktop` with `MasterPdfEditor.desktop` by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.